# ¿Como puedo generar un objeto a partir de un array?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo un array de varios array de este tipo

```
data = [ ["202010", 11.4], ["202011", 15.6 ], ["202012", 13.8 ], ["202013", 10.6 ] ]
```

Y necesito un array de objetos que tenga esta forma:

```
objectData = [
        {
          date: "202010",
          generate: 11.4,
          unit: 'kg'
        },
        {
          date: "202011",
          generate: 15.6,
          unit: 'kg'
        },
        {
          date: "202012",
          generate: 13.8,
          unit: 'kg'
        },
        {
          date: "202013",
          generate: 10.6,
          unit: 'kg'
        }
      ]
```

Quisiera también como se llama el tema de manejar todo esto y donde puedo leer documentación referente al tema. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Me he ido con la respuesta de Lobos, me iré a leer mas de la documentación acerca del manejo de objetos para tener más claridad.

Comment: Por favor para futuras preguntas procura agregar lo que lleves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver tu problema debes entender como funcionan los objetos de js y conocer métodos para manipular arreglos
.

[Documentación de referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)

Yo lo resolví usando la función `map()` la cual crea un nuevo arreglo con los resultados de la llamada a la función indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos.

Dentro de map retorno un nuevo objeto de js con `return { }` y dentro de ese objeto agrego las propiedades inicializadas con los valores del arreglo `e`.

```js
data = [ ["202010", 11.4], ["202011", 15.6 ], ["202012", 13.8 ], ["202013", 10.6 ] ];

//usar map para convertir los elementos del arreglo a objetos
var objeto = data.map(e => {
//retornar nuevo objeto con los atributos
return {
  date: e[0],
  generate: e[1],
  unit: 'kg'
};

});

console.log(objeto);
```

**Actualización**(aporte por BetaM):

```js
data = [ ["202010", 11.4], ["202011", 15.6 ], ["202012", 13.8 ], ["202013", 10.6 ] ];

let nuevo =  data.map((e) => e = {date :e[0], generate: e[1], unit: "kg"})

console.log(nuevo);
```

Comment: Te falto agregarle valor a unti pues ahorita sale undefined

Comment: De hecho puede quedar con la misma idea mas corta asi: **`let nuevo = data.map((e) => e = {date :e[0], generate: e[1], unit: "kg"})

console.log(nuevo)`**

Answer (score 0):

De manera simple y no tan corta puedes usar un bucle que recorra el array y llenar tu objeto.

Creamos el Objeto y array donde almacenara los objetos.

```js
var data = [ ["202010", 11.4], ["202011", 15.6 ], ["202012", 13.8 ], ["202013", 10.6 ]] ;

var ob=new Object();
var dat= new Array;
data.forEach(function (item,i) {
      ob["date"] = item[0];
      ob["generate"] = item[1];
      ob["unit"] = 'kg';   
      dat[i]=ob;
});

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(dat);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Aqui esta el Objeto</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Para no crear varias variables podrías usar .map y devolver el objeto con tus propiedades creadas